# File name of previous versions when versioning is on

Tags: development, document-library

How to get the file name of previous versions in a document library with versioning turned on. The OOB version history UI does not show the previous file name if the file name is changed. Suppose the file named `ABC.xls` is renamed to `XYZ.xls`. I don't find any way of getting the previous file name i.e. `ABC.xls` in the previous versions of the file. All versions of the file show the name as `XYZ.xls` which is current name of the file. Is it even possible? Here is my sample code:

```
SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(itemID);
SPFileVersionCollection fileVersions = listItem.File.Versions
foreach (SPFileVersion fileVersion in fileVersions)
{
    // The file name is always the current file name
    string fileName = fileVersion.File.Name
}
```

Comment: Perhaps is it inside SPFileVersion.Properties (I don't think though)?

Comment: No it isn't there as well :-(

Comment: So I think the filename is an un-versioned property

Comment: That is what I also feel. I have tried all possible ways to find it. The fact is that OOB version history also doesn't show it.